# angularJS cookie read response value

Tags: angularjs, cookies

if i made a request on my server with $http i the the followig response:

```
Request URL:http://www.test.tst/login
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=349AD3AC797C6AB28121ADA1766FF4A2
Host:www.test.tst
```

how can i read out the "Cookie:JSESSIONID=349AD3AC797C6AB28121ADA1766FF4A2"?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ngCookies](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies). In order to do it, you need to include the angular-cookies.js and the ngCookie in your module.

Then you can inject $cookies and get the cookie via its get function

```
<script src="angular-cookies.js">
```

And, in your Js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']).controller('Test', ['$cookies', '$scope', 
    function($cookies, $scope) {
        $scope.value = $cookies.get('JSESSIONID');
    }
]);
```

Comment: See other answer: $cookies does not expose a .get() method

Comment: @zewt112 Not sure what are you talking about. It's stated in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) that you have to use the `get` method...

Comment: Good spot, this is a recent change for v1.4. From the docs: "BREAKING CHANGE: $cookies no longer exposes properties that represent the current browser cookie values. Now you must use the get/put/remove/etc. methods as described below." 

If you're using v1.3 or below, there is no .get() method

Comment: Instead of `.get()`, you can directly access the value using `$cookies.sample = 'bar';`. [Seen here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Comment: (AngularJS v1.5.8) I tried the same code but not able to access cookies, my code:$timeout(function(){
                    $log.debug("Cookies : ");
                    $log.debug($cookies.getAll());
                    $log.debug($cookies.get('JSESSIONID'));
                    $log.debug($cookies.JSESSIONID);
                });

Answer (score -1):

$cookies does provide the .get function that is $cookieScope

If using $cookies you should just use $cookies.JSESSIONID

[Angular $cookies](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookies)

and

[Angular $cookieStore](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookieStore)

Comment: The `$cookieStore` service is deprecated. Read the docs that you linked.