# How to read a cookie in angularjs, after it was set in Web Api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am generating a token in web api using FormsAuthenticationTicket,
like that:

```
var user_json_str = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user);
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
    user.UserId,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false,
    user_json_str, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);//ENCRYPT THE TICKET
```

after that, I try to return it to the user in the response header like that:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("encTicket", encTicket));
```

I found the cookie in the client after that.

I read somewhere, that it's not suggested to use web api like that, so I tried this way:

```
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);//ENCRYPT THE TICKET
HttpResponseMessage ans = new HttpResponseMessage();
ans = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
ans.Content = new StringContent("Logged");
ans.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { new CookieHeaderValue("encTicket", encTicket) });
return ans;
```

this time the cookie didn't appear in the client ( I tried to read it using document.cookie in the chrome console).

what is the correct way to send cookie in the response header from web api?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513818/angularjs-cookie-read-response-value

Comment: but If I print in the console: document.cookie it already shows all the cookies that present on the page. I dont think $cookie will show me other hidden cookies.

Comment: I tried what you suggested anyway, and as I thought, the cookie is undefined. my problem is not to read the cookie, but to make sure that it come to the client

Comment: Check the response headers, is it showing up there?

Comment: when I read the response using 'Network' tab of chrome yes it shows. but in javascript it is abscent

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following ?

```
ans.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { new CookieHeaderValue("encTicket", encTicket)
{
  Expires = new DateTimeOffset( DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)),Path = "/"
} });
```