# Login site Angularjs, get cookies from server

Tags: angularjs, http, cookies, authentication

I'm doing login site in angularjs. Here's my code:

```
 $scope.signin = function(name) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'server_url',
            data: $.param({action: 'sign_in',
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
           .then(function (success) {
            $http.get({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'server_url',
            }).success(function (headers) {
                console.log(headers);
            })
                .error(function (data, status, headers) {
                    console.log(data, status, headers);
                    alert(data);
                });
        });
}
```

HTML:

```
        <input type="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">

        <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="signin()">Sign in</button>
```

In server headers i am getting cookies after post correct username ang password, but i don't know how to get it. My code don't work, in my console i have error - Error: $http:badreq
Bad Request Configuration

Thanks for asnwers in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularJS cookie read response value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513818/angularjs-cookie-read-response-value)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because the usage of `$http.get` is incorrect, it has nothing to do with Cookie -- if `Set-Cookie` header appears in response, the cookie is saved in browser and will be sent to server nex time, automatically.

According to AngularJS [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get), the usage of `$http.get` is as below, the first parameter is a String of URL, not a config object:

> get(url, [config]);

It seems what you need is raw `$http`, not `$http.get` shortcut:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'server_url',
})
```